# Suggestion: expanding the range of this board to include all the topics talked about on UK sites MoneySavingExpert and This is Money

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

[Background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163562/my-opened-thread-was-deleted-there-was-a-link-to-another-thread-i-commented-in): my other thread was deleted and from that thread there was a link to another thread about a similar subject. I even made a comment in that thread but it's just not possible to find that comment anymore so downvoting this because of that is not fair. I tried my best.

Take a look at UK sites This is Money and MoneySavingExpert. They are heavy on personal finance but also include topics like [cheap parcel delivery](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/shopping/cheap-parcel-delivery) options and [consumer rights issues](http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/bills/article-1677034/Two-year-warranty-EU-law.html). Not to mention mobile phone warranties, a murky topic.

So if you want to keep this board as *strictly* for personal finance only (whatever that means to you), then what name would you give to the topics discussed on This is Money and MoneySavingExpert but not discussed here? Is that a niche on it's own? Can you imagine its own, popular Stack Exchange board? You see?

So why not just include those topics here as well, huh? If it's good for the British, will be good here too.

Comment: This should be posted on Meta. Anyway, this is a Q&A board, not a discussion board. Can you feel the difference?

Comment: Can feel. I don't want to discuss here anything just Q&A on a slightly broader topic on personal finance that what's available at the moment.

Comment: @investor Then hang around and get to know us.

Comment: We *are* currently considering expansion of the topics to include **consumer issues & protection**, though not the other stuff you mentioned.  Refer to http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/597/shall-we-broaden-the-allowed-topics-to-include-consumer-issues-protection

Answer (score 6):

Have you read https://money.stackexchange.com/faq ? 
The range of questions for this board are spelled out fairly well there, and questions that are borderline are discussed here, often.

It's fine that you'd like to propose a scope change, but it seems to come with no background. Was there a question you felt appropriate that was closed?

You've has 8 question here, and only one has a positive vote rating. Why not spend time looking at some Q&A here, and decide if you have questions appropriate for this site? There are many discussion boards that may have the profile you seek. 
This site is not discussion, it's Q&A.

Comment: I read the FAQ. So do you suggest in _meta_ I can ask borderline issues like consumer protection, how to save on gas, etc. just like the above mentioned sites discuss? Btw. I find it a little bit redundant that there is already a _Trading_ board suggested in Area51 and this board also deals with investing in stocks. (My personal advice in this regard: ask for professional advice.)

Comment: On the site itself, questions are either answered and left open, or closed. The closed ones that are borderline are often discussed here. Meta is not the place to continue to propose questions to see if they pass. Respectfully, with 4600 questions asked at the site, you should easily get a feel of what type of board this is and what topics are on-topic.

Comment: *Meta* is for discussing issues about the site itself .. it is not a place to ask off-topic/borderline questions.  But, *Meta* is a great place to ask *if* a question would be considered off-topic or not.